# sbt creates multiple scala source directories

Tags: sbt, scala-2.11

I am trying to use sbt with IntelliJ Idea. When sbt 0.13.8 refreshes the project, it creates two scala source directories under src/main -> 'scala' and 'scala-2.11'

My scala version is 2.11.6

If I change sbt version to 0.13.5, the refresh creates only one directory -> src/main/scala.

Why could 0.13.8 be creating two directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbt has cross version source support in 0.13.8. So that's why when you ask it create empty sources, it creates these dirs.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases

Comment: Thanks. Under what circumstances should the flag be true?

Comment: I guess if you're not targeting different scalas or each of them don't have different source code, you can set crossPaths to false. Not sure why its true by default. I guess it doesn't hurt, just a bit strange that's all.